# Any significant bug or issues with Android Databinding Library?

Tags: java, android, data-binding

Can anyone who uses android databinding library (com.android.databinding:dataBinder) comment about this beta library?
In android developer site says "It might contain bugs, and it might not work for your use case, so use it at your own risk. " , so any issues or significant bug or bugs about it ?

Comment: magirtopcu, can you clarify what does a makes a bug significant to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been playing around with the databinding library for the past couple of weeks and it is surprisingly robust considering it is the very first version.

The only bug I have found so far has a workaround. I'll explain it below.

When using an `<include>` tag in your databinding layout file (a layout file which now uses the `<layout>` tag as the root), the generated code creates a binding for the `<include>` tag's parent ViewGroup.

When inflating the view using the DataBindingUtil, the application will crash with a when it tries to resolve the ViewGroup. There appears to be a different behaviour between the code generator and the runtime binding logic.

**Problem Example**

Here is an example layout with the problem mentioned above.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- This include causes no issues -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_content"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <!-- This include however causes the data binding to crash on the ScrollView -->
            <include
                layout="@layout/view_content"/>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And here is the included layout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"/>
</layout>
```

When attempting to use DataBindingUtil.setContentView the following crash occurs.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ScrollView.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

**Solution (Workaround)**

The temporary workaround I found is to bind a dummy value to the `<include>` tag's parent ViewGroup. This allows the databinder to find the ViewGroup at runtime, avoiding the crash.

Here is an example of the fix in action:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- This include causes no issues -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_content"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            bind:visibility="@{viewModel.dummyVisibility}">

            <!-- This include will not cause a problem now that the ScrollView has a value being bound -->
            <include
                layout="@layout/view_content"/>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And here is the very basic view model:

```
package com.example;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;
import android.view.View;

public class ViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    @Bindable
    public int getDummyVisibility() {
        // TODO: This is a work around. Currently data binding crashes on certain views if they don't have binding.
        return View.VISIBLE;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is fixed in future and this workaround won't be required!

**Edit**

I found another issue regarding custom binding adapters which I have raised at https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2421

Comment: did you report this on b.android.com ? We actually fixed a similar bug when inflating a data binder using `attachToRoot = true` . Not sure if this is caused by it though, would like to make sure it is fixed. (will create an internal bug report but would like to link to a public one if exists).

Comment: I raised a bug report for this after I made this post. Here is the [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2418). If it's a similar issue, perhaps add a comment instead of making a new issue?

Comment: Thanks,  I will verify it is fixed

Comment: I came across another bug which I also raised on the bug tracker. I edited my original post with the link!

Answer (score 3):

I found a bug with respect to ObservableField, filed [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177407).

According to the [databinding guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#observablefields) a model class may contain ObservableField attributes to keep it's attribute definitions short. Example from the guide:

```
private static class User extends BaseObservable {
    public final ObservableField<String> firstName =
       new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableField<String> lastName =
       new ObservableField<>();
    public final ObservableInt age = new ObservableInt();
}
```

By using this class the name attributes in class BR are not generated and the implementation classes can't be compiled, because they refer to them. Exception: Those attributes are also defined as variables in the layout XML, which is not the case in the example layout of the guide:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.lastName}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

BR.user is defined; BR.firstName, BR.lastName and BR.age are not.

Changing the User class like this solves the issue:

```
private static class User extends BaseObservable {
    @Bindable
    public final ObservableField<String> firstName =
       new ObservableField<>();
    @Bindable
    public final ObservableField<String> lastName =
       new ObservableField<>();
    @Bindable
    public final ObservableInt age = new ObservableInt();
}
```

In my opinion when using Observable* types their names should be added to BR.java by default and @Bindable should be obsolete.

At least the guide should be fixed by adding the @Bindable annotation to the ObservableField example code.

Took me two days to analyse and fix this issue.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in the latest Version of Android Databinding Library.

Answer (score 1):

It does not currently support @style. For instance:

```
style="@{viewModel.getStyle() ?? @style/default_style}"
```

The above would attempt to set a default style found in the styles resource if getStyle() returned null. Unfortunately this is not possible, but would make for a very powerful addition to data binding imo.

Answer (score 1):

When I have implemented the MVVM pattern with Data Binding Library on Android, I found several bugs. Some of them were mentioned here already. Although, I can add another bug that related to the events. Events can not include parameters. It implies that Data Binding Library doesn't have an important ability to transfer some extra information when sending events. However, I hope that in the next release it will be fixed. Until that happens, look at the solution of this problem here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185097